# File is getting crashed while uploading to BIM360 through Autodesk Platform Services URLs

Tags: autodesk-forge

Revit file crashes via uploading to BIM360 through URLs provided by Autodesk Platform Services. The same file when uploaded by the options provided by the BIM360 webpage, works fine.
I am using the URLs mentioned in the below link to upload a Revit file to BIM360:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/

Comment: So, have you followed all steps in that tutorial? In each step, it shows succeed? How large with the model size?